# Why doesn't my code recognize the index.php file in the rest folder, along with other classes and files

Tags: php, flightphp

I am working on a project for my Into to Web Programming course and we've been using PHP, more specifically Flight PHP. I've ran into an issue where I can't access anything on the project. Doesn't recognize index.php in the rest folder, or other classes, files, etc. The code works perfectly fine on my colleagues laptop, but doesn't at all for me. I've googled everything I can, ChatGPT, my TA and my prof., but she didn't have much time to help me. I am not very familiar with PHP so I don't know what else I can do, but ask the internet for help.Here is the repo: [removed]

I'm on Windows 10, running wamp64 server for hosting and MySQL for the database.If someone figures out the problem, please let me know as I'm getting really desperate since the midterms are soon.

I tried googling everything I could come up with, using ChatGPT/BingAI, getting help from my TA, and a little help from my prof. but she didn't have much time to help me with my "nothing works" problem.
The index.php file doesn't recognize other classes/files I've written, stating that they don't exist, even when I write the complete directory from C drive to file.

Comment: you need to configure the root folder path for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

The problem wasn't with wamp, or the code, but rather MySQL Workbench and the installment order. I had Workbench from earlier projects which was causing the problem.

To solve: Uninstall everything (wamp, Workbench) and install wamp first, set everything up. Then just download and install only the Workbench from [here](https://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.33.0.msi).
Afterwards just connect Workbench to "local instance wampmysql" and then it should work normally.